# Woocommerce Border

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a strange border around my shopping cart total ("WARENKORB SUMME") since today.
Please check the screenshot below

How can I get rid of it?

It is a Wordpress/WooCoomerce store

I haven't changed anything - I think it came from an automatic update

[Cart Total Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOK4U.png)

Comment: You should inspect the element in developer tools and check CSS styles in this box. Then use Theme File Editor to rewrite CSS settings in this box.

Answer (score 0):

You can just inspect using the developer toolbar in your browser and check from where the extra border is added. Basically, you would need to tweak the CSS codes a bit or add some extra CSS codes to overwrite the default border style.